# HTML email Link Tracking

Tags: facebook, twitter, html-email

I need to track the twitter and facebook url's on my HTML email. This will be sent via our own server (and software) which is hosted with Memset. We won't be using an off the shelf email system such as Mailchimp.

I can't use bit.ly as our server builds the url's just before they are sent. Is there any other way to track the links?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I can't use bit.ly as our server builds the url's just before they are sent." — Why would that stop you using http://dev.bitly.com/ ?

Comment: @Quentin Actually I have started using bit.ly recently and don't know much about dev.bitly.com. Could you please tell me how can I do this with dev.bitly.com..

Comment: You take your code that generates your URLs and the email and have it use the bitly API to generate a short URL for each long URL.